KeyError: 'Exception encountered when calling Functional.call()
I am trying to construct a model that accepts two inputs. Within this model, I've designed three blocks: two correspond to the structure of the first blocks of EfficientNetB0 up to block 4 (A), while the third block (B) mirrors the architecture of EfficientNetB0's final blocks 5, 6, and 7. I've created the function 'build_model()' to create this model, and everything seems to function correctly when calling the function and executing model.summary(). However, upon applying the model.fit()function, I encountered the following error:
Has anyone encountered this error before?
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StagingError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[50], line 24
     21 with strategy.scope(): 
     22     model = build_model()
---> 24 model.fit(train_gen, verbose=1, validation_data = valid_gen, epochs=10, callbacks = [LR2])
     25 model.save_weights(f'EffNet_v{VER}_f{i}.weights.h5')
     26 oof = model.predict(valid_gen, verbose=1)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py:123, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    120     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
    121     # To get the full stack trace, call:
    122     # `keras.config.disable_traceback_filtering()`
--> 123     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    124 finally:
    125     del filtered_tb

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/polymorphic_function/autograph_util.py:52, in py_func_from_autograph.<locals>.autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     50 except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
     51   if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
---> 52     raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
     53   else:
     54     raise

StagingError: in user code:

    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 105, in one_step_on_data  **
        return self.train_step(data)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/backend/tensorflow/trainer.py", line 56, in train_step
        y_pred = self(x, training=True)
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 123, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/ops/function.py", line 161, in _run_through_graph
        output_tensors.append(tensor_dict[id(x)])

    KeyError: 'Exception encountered when calling Functional.call().\n\n\x1b[1m137598607979904\x1b[0m\n\nArguments received by Functional.call():\n  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 256, 512, 3), dtype=float32)\n  • training=True\n  • mask=None' 

Function to build the model:
from tensorflow.keras.applications import EfficientNetB0
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Concatenate, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.losses import KLDivergence
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Lambda, Concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer


# Define the names of the layers corresponding to blocks A and B
block_a_layers = ['block1a_dwconv', 'block1a_bn', 'block1a_activation', 'block1a_se_squeeze', 'block1a_se_reshape', 'block1a_se_reduce', 'block1a_se_expand', 'block1a_se_excite', 'block1a_project_conv', 'block1a_project_bn', 
                  'block2a_expand_conv', 'block2a_expand_bn', 'block2a_expand_activation', 'block2a_dwconv_pad', 'block2a_dwconv', 'block2a_bn', 'block2a_activation', 'block2a_se_squeeze', 'block2a_se_reshape', 'block2a_se_reduce', 'block2a_se_expand', 'block2a_se_excite', 'block2a_project_conv', 'block2a_project_bn', 'block2b_expand_conv', 'block2b_expand_bn', 'block2b_expand_activation', 'block2b_dwconv', 'block2b_bn', 'block2b_activation', 'block2b_se_squeeze', 'block2b_se_reshape', 'block2b_se_reduce', 'block2b_se_expand', 'block2b_se_excite', 'block2b_project_conv', 'block2b_project_bn', 'block2b_drop', 'block2b_add', 
                  'block3a_expand_conv', 'block3a_expand_bn', 'block3a_expand_activation', 'block3a_dwconv_pad', 'block3a_dwconv', 'block3a_bn', 'block3a_activation', 'block3a_se_squeeze', 'block3a_se_reshape', 'block3a_se_reduce', 'block3a_se_expand', 'block3a_se_excite', 'block3a_project_conv', 'block3a_project_bn', 'block3b_expand_conv', 'block3b_expand_bn', 'block3b_expand_activation', 'block3b_dwconv', 'block3b_bn', 'block3b_activation', 'block3b_se_squeeze', 'block3b_se_reshape', 'block3b_se_reduce', 'block3b_se_expand', 'block3b_se_excite', 'block3b_project_conv', 'block3b_project_bn', 'block3b_drop', 'block3b_add', 
                  'block4a_expand_conv', 'block4a_expand_bn', 'block4a_expand_activation', 'block4a_dwconv_pad', 'block4a_dwconv', 'block4a_bn', 'block4a_activation', 'block4a_se_squeeze', 'block4a_se_reshape', 'block4a_se_reduce', 'block4a_se_expand', 'block4a_se_excite', 'block4a_project_conv', 'block4a_project_bn', 'block4b_expand_conv', 'block4b_expand_bn', 'block4b_expand_activation', 'block4b_dwconv', 'block4b_bn', 'block4b_activation', 'block4b_se_squeeze', 'block4b_se_reshape', 'block4b_se_reduce', 'block4b_se_expand', 'block4b_se_excite', 'block4b_project_conv', 'block4b_project_bn', 'block4b_drop', 'block4b_add', 'block4c_expand_conv', 'block4c_expand_bn', 'block4c_expand_activation', 'block4c_dwconv', 'block4c_bn', 'block4c_activation', 'block4c_se_squeeze', 'block4c_se_reshape', 'block4c_se_reduce', 'block4c_se_expand', 'block4c_se_excite', 'block4c_project_conv', 'block4c_project_bn', 
                  'block4c_drop', 'block4c_add'
]

block_b_layers = [
    'block5a_expand_conv', 'block5a_expand_bn', 'block5a_expand_activation', 'block5a_dwconv', 'block5a_bn', 'block5a_activation', 'block5a_se_squeeze', 'block5a_se_reshape', 'block5a_se_reduce', 'block5a_se_expand', 'block5a_se_excite', 'block5a_project_conv', 'block5a_project_bn', 'block5b_expand_conv', 'block5b_expand_bn', 'block5b_expand_activation', 'block5b_dwconv', 'block5b_bn', 'block5b_activation', 'block5b_se_squeeze', 'block5b_se_reshape', 'block5b_se_reduce', 'block5b_se_expand', 'block5b_se_excite', 'block5b_project_conv', 'block5b_project_bn', 'block5b_drop', 'block5b_add', 'block5c_expand_conv', 'block5c_expand_bn', 'block5c_expand_activation', 'block5c_dwconv', 'block5c_bn', 'block5c_activation', 'block5c_se_squeeze', 'block5c_se_reshape', 'block5c_se_reduce', 'block5c_se_expand', 'block5c_se_excite', 'block5c_project_conv', 'block5c_project_bn', 'block5c_drop', 'block5c_add', 
    'block6a_expand_conv', 'block6a_expand_bn', 'block6a_expand_activation', 'block6a_dwconv_pad', 'block6a_dwconv', 'block6a_bn', 'block6a_activation', 'block6a_se_squeeze', 'block6a_se_reshape', 'block6a_se_reduce', 'block6a_se_expand', 'block6a_se_excite', 'block6a_project_conv', 'block6a_project_bn', 'block6b_expand_conv', 'block6b_expand_bn', 'block6b_expand_activation', 'block6b_dwconv', 'block6b_bn', 'block6b_activation', 'block6b_se_squeeze', 'block6b_se_reshape', 'block6b_se_reduce', 'block6b_se_expand', 'block6b_se_excite', 'block6b_project_conv', 'block6b_project_bn', 'block6b_drop', 'block6b_add', 'block6c_expand_conv', 'block6c_expand_bn', 'block6c_expand_activation', 'block6c_dwconv', 'block6c_bn', 'block6c_activation', 'block6c_se_squeeze', 'block6c_se_reshape', 'block6c_se_reduce', 'block6c_se_expand', 'block6c_se_excite', 'block6c_project_conv', 'block6c_project_bn', 'block6c_drop', 'block6c_add', 'block6d_expand_conv', 'block6d_expand_bn', 'block6d_expand_activation', 'block6d_dwconv', 'block6d_bn', 'block6d_activation', 'block6d_se_squeeze', 'block6d_se_reshape', 'block6d_se_reduce', 'block6d_se_expand', 'block6d_se_excite', 'block6d_project_conv', 'block6d_project_bn', 'block6d_drop', 'block6d_add',
    'block7a_expand_conv', 'block7a_expand_bn', 'block7a_expand_activation', 'block7a_dwconv', 'block7a_bn', 'block7a_activation', 'block7a_se_squeeze', 'block7a_se_reshape', 'block7a_se_reduce', 'block7a_se_expand', 'block7a_se_excite', 'block7a_project_conv', 'block7a_project_bn'
]

def build_model():
    inp1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(229, 232, 4))
    inp2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(128, 256, 4))
    
    inp_A1 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256, 512, 3))
    inp_A2 = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256, 512, 3))
    
    input_B = tf.keras.Input(shape = (None,None,160))
    
    # Load the EfficientNetB0 model pre-trained on ImageNet
    base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0( include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=None)
    
    # Reshape Input X1 229x232x4 => 458x464x3 Monotone Image => Resize to 256x512x3
    x1 = [inp1[:,:,:,i:i+1] for i in range(2)]
    x1 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(x1)
    x2 = [inp1[:,:,:,i+2:i+3] for i in range(2)]
    x2 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(x2)
    x_1 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=2)([x1,x2])
    x_1 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([x_1,x_1,x_1])
    x_1 =  tf.keras.layers.Resizing(height=256, width=512)(x_1)
  
    # Reshape Input X2 128x256x4 => 256x512x3
    x3 = [inp2[:,:,:,i:i+1] for i in range(2)]
    x3 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(x3)
    x4 = [inp2[:,:,:,i+2:i+3] for i in range(2)]
    x4 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=1)(x4)
    x_2 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=2)([x3,x4])
    x_2 = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=3)([x_2,x_2,x_2])

    # Create the model for block A
    block_a_outputs_1 = [base_model.get_layer(name).output for name in block_a_layers]
    block_a_outputs_2 = [base_model.get_layer(name).output for name in block_a_layers]
    block_a_model_1 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp_A1, outputs=block_a_outputs_1)
    block_a_model_2 = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp_A2, outputs=block_a_outputs_2)
    
    # Create the model for block B
    block_b_outputs = [base_model.get_layer(name1).output for name1 in block_b_layers]
    block_b_model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input_B, outputs=block_b_outputs)
    
    # Get the outputs from block A for both inputs
    block_a_output_1 = block_a_model_1(x_1)
    block_a_output_2 = block_a_model_2(x_2)

    # Concatenate the outputs from block A
    concatenated_output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)([block_a_output_1[-1],block_a_output_2[-1]])

    
    # Get the output from block B using the concatenated features
    block_b_output = block_b_model(concatenated_output)
    #block_b_output = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate(axis=-1)(block_b_output[-1])
    
    # OUTPUT
    x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(block_b_output[-1])
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(6,activation='softmax', dtype='float32')(x)
    
    # COMPILE MODEL
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=(inp1, inp2), outputs=x)
    opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate = 1e-3)
    loss = tf.keras.losses.KLDivergence()
    model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer = opt) 

        
    return model

Code for training:
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, GroupKFold
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K, gc
VER = 2
all_oof = []
all_true = []

gkf = GroupKFold(n_splits=5)

for i, (train_index, valid_index) in enumerate(gkf.split(train, train.target, train.patient_id)):
    print('#'*25)
    print(f'### Fold {i+1}')
    
    train_gen = DataGenerator(train.iloc[train_index], shuffle=True, batch_size=32)
    valid_gen = DataGenerator(train.iloc[valid_index], shuffle=False, batch_size=64)
    
    print(f'### train size {len(train_index)}, valid size {len(valid_index)}')
    print('#'*25)
    
    K.clear_session()
    
    with strategy.scope(): 
        model = build_model()
        
    model.fit(train_gen, verbose=1, validation_data = valid_gen, epochs=10, callbacks = [LR2])

Everything seems fine except when fitting the model

Try installing TensorFlow==2.10. It worked for me!

Try to add inputs to base_model:
base_model = tf.keras.applications.EfficientNetB0( include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=None, input_tensor=inputs) 

